# Breadcrumbs for wxWidgets treeCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets, breadcrumbs

I would like to add breadcrumbs navigation to a `treeCtrl` in `wxWidgets` C++ - similar to IE Explorer. Does anyone know if that exists somewhere? Or at least something similar to use as a starting point? Ideally I would like the breadcrumb to look and act natively on mac/unix/windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no breadcrumb control in wxWidgets, probably because there aren't actually native controls in Windows or GTK. The easiest way to create such a control is probably to draw it yourself, on OSX there is [NSPathControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) which I think may do what you want. There are also plenty links from this [GTK bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331703) on the issue with ideas, mockups and existing controls.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I will explore those.